# FirebaseUser currentUser is showing array

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

When I debug currentUser it is shwoing value: {zzi@7093}, why it is showing in array, but I've registered only single user.

```
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
 @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (currentUser != null) {
            databaseReference.child(USERS).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child(ONLINE).setValue(TRUE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (currentUser != null) {
            databaseReference.child(USERS).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child(ONLINE).setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is most likely the hash code of the object. So `{zzi@7093}` is just an opaque string representation that uniquely identifies the user object in the current instance of your app.

If you want to know more about the user, you should call its public methods, such as the `getUid()` that you're already using.

Answer (score 0):

That is an `object` and not an `array`. The `getCurrentUser()` method returns a `FirebaseUser`, hence it is **impossible** for the method to return an `array`.

Please see the documentation for [FirebaseAuth#getCurrentUser()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#getCurrentUser())

From the documentation:

> Returns the currently signed-in FirebaseUser or null if there is none.
>
> Use getCurrentUser() != null to check if a user is signed in.
>
> Returns the signed-in user or null